# uv4l and janus "use of hardware codec is disabled in this restricted edition"

Tags: uv4l, h264

I have a rpi 3 with the v2 camera running stretch 9.1.  I've installed raspicam and uv4l according to the instructions on linux-projects.org.

I have the janus gateway setup on a separate box.  I am trying to use the h264 hardware encoder and stream to the video room plugin in janus.

Using the streaming front-end on the rpi, I can go to the webrtc page (/stream/webrtc) and view the camera.  Without the "Force use of hardware codec" checked, the cpu load is about 120% overall (from top).  With that box checked, it drops to about 60%.  I've enabled debug level 7 for uv4l, but I don't see anything in syslog to confirm the video codec being used.

Below are some of the settings I have in /etc/uv4l/uv4l-raspicam.conf:

encoding = h264

server-option = --webrtc-enable-hw-codec=yes

When using the streaming server "Join a room with Janus" page, I see the restriction message below:

[image]

On the janus side, if I leave VP8 as the default codec for the video room, it works.  If I change it to h264 only, I don't get video.  And the Janus debug shows that the uvl4/webrtc on rpi isn't offering h264 in the sdp negotiation.

I'm not sure what "restricted edition" means.  Is this a limitation of uv4l or the webrtc implementation?  Or something with my rpi or camera?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The author of U4VL is elusive and secretive. I suggest using the contact form on www.linux-projects.org to negotiate a contract for commercial use. The pseudonyms of the author on the Raspberry Pi StackExchange are "**prinxis**" and "**RpiName**" on raspberrypi.org - you can try to contact him/her that way too.